# How do I copy a compiled IPA to my iOS device?

Tags: ios, ipa

I have a developer account and I'm used to authoring my own apps.  Recently another developer I'm working with wants me to test their application on my device.  He has already added my devices ID to his provisioning profiles and provided me with a compiled IPA, however I don't know how to go about copying this IPA to my iOS device.  The workflow with XCode doesn't seem to be what I'm used to when working with my own source.

He has specifically asked me not to use Test Flight.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

What we do (at work) is: we did put up a small web page with a link to the IPA.
You click it and the device will install it.

Very simple, and very easy to distribute the IPA to the testers.
And only devices in the provisioning profile are able to install.

Answer (score 1):

I use Dropbox to share Ad-Hoc builds with testers. Process as follows:

**Distributing Ad Hoc iOS build using Dropbox:**

***Make sure iOS provisioning profile contains client’s/tester's devices’ UDIDs, otherwise build would not get installed on their devices and Dropbox is installed on your MAC machine.***

1. Set target device as **iOS Device** and prepare an iOS App Archive by going to ***Product -> Archive***.
2. Organizer window will open once archiving is finished, which shows all previous archives if any.
3. Select the latest archive and click ***Distribute***, select ***Save for Enterprise or Ad Hoc Deployment*** option and click Next.
4. Select the provisioning profile to sign .ipa file which contains all the target devices’ UDIDs and click ***Export***.
5. After signing is completed, a Finder window opens which asks where to save the final .ipa file, select **Dropbox** folder where you want to put the .ipa. At the bottom of Finder window check the option ***Save for Enterprise Distribution***.
   As soon as Save for Enterprise Distribution is checked some text fields will appear, enter a dummy url (e.g http://dl.myipalink.com) in the ***Application URL*** field and app name in ***Title*** field and click Save.
6. Go to Dropbox folder on your MAC, you will find two files (viz. .ipa and .plist) are generated for you.

   6.1) Right click on .ipa file and select ***Share Dropbox Link***, link will get copied to clipboard. Paste it in text editor and replace **www** with **dl**  in the link. Now your .ipa link is ready, this is your   ***Application URL*** discussed above in step 5.

   6.2) Open .plist file and replace dummy url with the .ipa link which we have prepared in step 6.1.

   6.3) Right click on .plist file and click ***Share Dropbox Link***,  paste the link somewhere and replace **www** with **dl**. This is the same thing we did in step 6.1. Your .plist link is ready.
7. Create an .html file e.g as shown below in the same Dropbox folder in which .ipa and .plist files were saved or any other location inside Dropbox folder.

   ```
   <!doctype html>
   <head>
   <title>MY APP</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <h1><a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&amp;url=YOUR .PLIST LINK” > Download My App  </a></h1><br><br>
   </html>
   ```

replace with the **YOUR .PLIST LINK** with .plist link which we have prepared in step 6.3. Save the html file.

8. Right click on .html file and click ***Share Dropbox Link***, link to .html file will get copied to clipboard. Send this link to client/tester. Save the link for future convenience.
9. Next time if you want to update the  build, simply replace existing .ipa with the new one.

Hope now you can distribute iOS build.

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone configuration utility can be used for this - open the app (I can't remember if you need to download it first) and drag in the ipa, connect your device and you can install it there.

You can also use iTunes, but that may not be something you want to do on your work machine with your personal device, as you have to sync the whole thing rather than just install a single app.

Comment: As it turns out the provisioning profile was not set up correctly, however it took the iPhone Config Utility to tell me that (I had tried web-distribution, xcode, and itunes before that).  I wish I'd known about this app sooner, either way.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have him put the ipa online and point new users to that url

Answer (score 0):

There is one another way to add `.ipa` to device that we use on work -- is xCode Device Manager -- 
just open application section of target device and drop `.ipa` into list of already installed app