# ios app distribure wireless / over the air

Tags: ios, xcode

I am investigating ways to get app distributed over the air. I use XCODE-6.1

As per this article, I need to generate .plist and .ipa while "Archiving"

http://aaronparecki.com/articles/2011/01/21/1/how-to-distribute-your-ios-apps-over-the-air

However, I could only generate .ipa with XCODE 6.1

How can I get .plist generated as mentioned above?

Comment: I used to distribute builds using Dropbox, here is the link to my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21800958/1526629. May be it can help you.